# Why my sass style does not apply on my html code

Tags: sass, next.js

I try to create a website with sass technology but when I give the classname on my header the style is not applied and I don't understand why.

The name of my sass file is Login.module.scss and import it in my login.js file.

Thanks for your help,

```sass
.nav-login {
  background-color: white;
  height: 5vh;

  nav ul li a {
    color: #FA5858;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

```next-js
import styles from "@/styles/Login.module.scss"

export default function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header/>
    </>
  )
}

function Header() {
  return (
    <header className={styles.navLogin}>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href={"#"}>Logidiese</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>FR</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Contacts</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}
```

[image: the result of my code]

Comment: change className in sass .nav-login to .navLogin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nav-login` != `navLogin`

Update the class name in the scss file to match